# Sort an array based on dictionary

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

I am consfused that a sorted array is given, how to perform a dictionary sort on it **without converting them into a string** in java or c language

```
input: {1, 2, 3, 15, 22, 30, 100, 110, 150, 160, 250, 300}

output: {1, 100, 110, 15, 150, 160, 2, 22, 250, 3, 30, 300}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is just not to save the array as an array of strings at the end, you could just use a custom `Comparator`:

```
Arrays.sort(myArray, 0, myArray.length, Comparator.comparing(String::valueOf));
```